# Leer dato con clase BufferedReader en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un dato tipo short al que quiero leer.
lo que hago es pedir que el usuario ingrese un dato para el dato short:               System.out.println("\nIngrese dato para Short");

y despues trato de leer el dato que el usuario ingresó para mostrarlo:
shortDato = Short.parseShort(reader.readLine());

Cuando lo muestro solo lo hago de esta manera:
System.out.println("El dato que ingresó para Short es: " + shortDato);

Me da el siguiente error y sospecho que es por la parte cuando se va a leer el dato.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:121)
    at java.base/java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:147)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:381)

Pido su ayuda para un primerizo en apuros.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner tu código? he intentado esto y no he tenido problemas:

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter your number: ");

    short number = Short.parseShort(reader.readLine());

    System.out.println("your number: " + number);
}
```

Lo que el error te está diciendo es que estás tratando de crear un short a partir del String "". Por lo que sí, el problema es con la lectura de tu número.
Qué tengas buen día!